# dir-local variable not set for specific mode

Tags: directory-local-variables

I have the following `.dir-locals.el` file.

```lisp
((nil . ((ffip-project-root . "~/projects/xyzzy/git")
         (my-invalid-imports . ("org.junit.[A-Z]"))))
 (jdee-mode . ((my-invalid-imports . ("org.junit.[A-Z]")))))
```

The `ffip-project-root` variable has been set correctly since I created the file.  I recently tried to add the `my-invalid-imports` variable.  Since that would only apply to Java file, which would be in `jdee-mode`, I added the mode-specific entry.  When I reloaded a file in a subdirectory, `my-invalid-imports` had the default value, but `ffip-project-root` had the value from `.dir-locals.el`.

When I added the line to the global block, `my-invalid-imports` was set correctly.

I am guessing that I am screwing up the syntax in the mode-specific entry, but it seems like it should be right from how I read the docs.

Any ideas why the mode-specific version does not work?

**Attempt 1**

```lisp
((nil . ((ffip-project-root . "~/projects/xyzzy/git")
         ))
 (jdee-mode . ((my-invalid-imports . ("org.junit.[A-Z]")))))
```

The expected and actual values are

- in a file with `major-mode` set to `jdee-mode` by the major mode command.

  - Expected: `my-invalid-imports` is a list with one item: `("org.junit.[A-Z]")`
  - Actual: `my-invalid-imports` is `nil`
- in a file with `major-mode` set to `fundamental-mode` by the major mode command.

  - Expected: `my-invalid-imports` is a `nil` (the global value).  This is the **desired** result
  - Actual: `my-invalid-imports` is `nil`

**Attempt 2**

```lisp
((nil . ((ffip-project-root . "~/projects/xyzzy/git")
         (my-invalid-imports . ("org.junit.[A-Z]"))
         ))
 (jdee-mode . ((my-invalid-imports . ("org.junit.[A-Z]")))))
```

The expected and actual values are

- in a file with `major-mode` set to `jdee-mode` by the major mode command.

  - Expected: `my-invalid-imports` is a list with one item: `("org.junit.[A-Z]")`
  - Actual: `my-invalid-imports` is that list. This is the **desired** result
- in a file with `major-mode` set to `fundamental-mode` by the major mode command.

  - Expected: `my-invalid-imports` is a the 1 element list
  - Actual: `my-invalid-imports` is the 1 element list

EDIT: Fix syntax to correct way to set a list.  It does not change the actual problem.

Comment: Should this: `(my-invalid-imports . ("org.junit.[A-Z]"))` perhaps be this: `(my-invalid-imports . "org.junit.[A-Z]")`? (FWIW, I'm a bit lost in what you tried (no examples), and what the effect of each try was.)

Comment: are you editing by hand or using `M-x add-dir-local-variable`?

Comment: I am editing by hand.  I tried `add-dir-local-variable` and could not figure out how to not specify a mode, so I started editing by hand.

Comment: The value of `my-invalid-imports` is supposed to be a list, which, in this case, has 1 value.